# Save attachment with subject name

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to save attachments from all e-mails in a certain folder. This is a daily process so it also deletes downloaded attachments.

The names of the files are not constant and I need them to have the same name after saving as subject name from e-mail they came from.

Every e-mail contains one attachment. Is it possible to modify current code so it saves with subject name instead of attachment name?

```vb
Sub Spremanje()
    ' Ask the user to select a file system folder for saving the attachments
    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Dim fsSaveFolder As Object
    Set fsSaveFolder = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Mapa za spremanje izvještaja", 1)
    If fsSaveFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' Note:  BrowseForFolder doesn't add a trailing slash

    ' Ask the user to select an Outlook folder to process
    Dim olPurgeFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olPurgeFolder = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
    If olPurgeFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Iteration variables
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
  
    Dim sSavePathFS As String
    Dim sDelAtts

    For Each msg In olPurgeFolder.Items

    sDelAtts = ""

    ' We check each msg for attachments as opposed to using .Restrict("[Attachment] > 0")
    ' on our olPurgeFolder.Items collection.  The collection returned by the Restrict method
    ' will be dynamically updated each time we remove an attachment.  Each update will
    ' reindex the collection.  As a result, it does not provide a reliable means for iteration.
    ' This is why the For Each loops will not work.
    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

      ' This While loop is controlled via the .Delete method
      ' which will decrement msg.Attachments.Count by one each time.
      While msg.Attachments.Count > 0

        ' Save the file
        sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder.Self.Path & "\" & msg.Subject(1).FileName
        msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS

        ' Build up a string to denote the file system save path(s)
        ' Format the string according to the msg.BodyFormat.
        If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            sDelAtts = sDelAtts & vbCrLf & "<file://" & sSavePathFS & ">"
        Else
            sDelAtts = sDelAtts & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & sSavePathFS & "'>" & sSavePathFS & "</a>"
        End If

        ' Delete the current attachment.  We use a "1" here instead of an "i"
        ' because the .Delete method will shrink the size of the msg.Attachments
        ' collection for us.  Use some well placed Debug.Print statements to see
        ' the behavior.
        msg.Attachments(1).Delete

      Wend

      ' Modify the body of the msg to show the file system location of
      ' the deleted attachments.
      If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
        msg.Body = msg.Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts
      Else
        msg.HTMLBody = msg.HTMLBody & "<p></p><p>" & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts & "</p>"
      End If

      ' Save the edits to the msg.  If you forget this line, the attachments will not be deleted.
      msg.Save

    End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code the path is set in the following way:

```
' Save the file
sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder.Self.Path & "\" & msg.Subject(1).FileName
```

To use a subject you can use the Subject property in the code:

```
sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder.Self.Path & "\" & msg.Subject & " - " & msg.Attachments(1).FileName
```

But you need to create a unique filename for the attached file, so it makes sense to introduce some kind of ID for the attached files. It can be a date string when the item was received ([ReceivedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime)) or any other identifier which could uniquely related to a particular attachments.

---

Also I'd suggest replacing the while loop in the code, so that you could the the currently iterated mail item in the code without maintaining another indexes:

```
 ' This While loop is controlled via the .Delete method
  ' which will decrement msg.Attachments.Count by one each time.
  While msg.Attachments.Count > 0
```

Instead, you could use reverse for loop in the code.

```
For i = msg.Attachments.Count To 1 Step -1
```

So, you may get the item easily:

```
Set att = msg.Attachments.Item(i)
```